# Converting Unix epoch time to extended ISO8601

Tags: datetime, hadoop, presto, amazon-athena

I have 3 tables I would like to work on using the date, however one of the tables includes the date in unix epoch format. Here is an example of the 3 fields:

```
Table1: 2017-02-01T07:58:40.756031Z
Table2: 2017-02-07T10:16:46Z
Table3: 1489236559
```

I would like to convert the date in table 3 to match the format of table 2 as closely as possible. This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT cast(from_unixtime(tstart) as timestamp) as ISODATE from scada_logs
```

This gives me something tantalizingly close, but not quite there. Here is what I get:

```
ISODATE
2017-03-20 14:31:06.000
2017-03-20 14:31:06.000
```

I've played around with this for a couple of hours but I'm not getting any closer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Option 1: date_format

```
presto> select date_format(from_unixtime(1489236559),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ');
        _col0
----------------------
 2017-03-11T12:49:19Z
```

#### Option 2: to_iso8601

```
presto> select to_iso8601(from_unixtime(1489236559));
          _col0
--------------------------
 2017-03-11T12:49:19.000Z
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, I receive an error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:33: Column 'yyyy-mm-dd't'hh:mm:ss'z'' cannot be resolved. This is actually on AWS Athena, which uses Hive. Perhaps it's a non-standard version?

Comment: Actually AWS Athena uses prestodb and not hiveql. See updated answer

Comment: And for older Hive versions that do not support `date_format` (i.e. before V1.2) you still have good old `printf`... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - AWS Athena uses presto, not HiveQL