# How to convert Epoch to date in athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have written a query to convert epoch to date conversion in Athena but the result is not expected

```
select from_unixtime(cast(epoch_values as bigint))as dates from mybdbase
```

result is :

| dates |
| --- |
| +54113-07-13 10:11:53.000 |
| +54113-07-13 10:11:57.000 |

The year is shown in the above table, How to solve this?

Comment: Below links can be helpful..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927726/converting-unix-epoch-time-to-extended-iso8601

https://ahana.io/answers/how-do-i-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-a-date-or-something-more-human-readable-with-sql/

Comment: Interested in seeing the current value of `epoch_values` ...

Comment: 1632816120779
1632121233095 and so on like this i have lot of epoch numbers then what's the case to convert them to date

Comment: It seems your `epoch_values` are a factor 1000 to high, try to divide them

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```sql
from_unixtime(event_timestamp/1000000)
```

You could validate the results with this page:
https://www.epochconverter.com/